# Why is useState() not setting the default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created following reactComponent. From what I understand useState([]); should set the comments variable to an array. But it does not. I get an exeption that I Try to run .map() on an object. What I have to do is Object.values(comments) to make it work but I don't understand why. My api definetly returns an array of comment objects.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default ({ postId }) => {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:4001/posts/${postId}/comments`
    );

    setComments(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const renderedComments = comments.map(comment => {
    return <li key={comment.id}>{comment.content}</li>;
  });

  return <ul>{renderedComments}</ul>;
};
```

Comment: Speculation (lacking a [mcve]): the default value is an empty array, but then you call `setComments(res.data)` and set it to an object.

Comment: Whats the output of console.log(res.data) ? Are you sure that its an array ?

Comment: you are both totally right. I had a syntax error in my backend and when there where no comments the endpoint returned nothing instead on an empty array. After I fixed that the code worked.

Comment: you should always check if you have data before render, this way allows you to handle what to show in case there is no data.

Comment: Console log is your friend. If you have issues with a value not being what you expect, then the first thing to do is find every place you are setting that value, and double check what you are setting it to. It's not good enough to assume that your API works as expected. Prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of state is correct as far as I can tell, the fact that `Object.values` works on the data handed back to you implies it is definitely either an object or an array, have you run `Array.isArray(res.data)` as part of your troubleshooting process?

As stated by a commenter above, the most likely scenario is that you are getting an object back from your back end. Other things you can do to confirm its the data handed back to you at fault would be to simply comment out your `useEffect` and see if it still throws the same exception.