# why is the useState hook not setting the value until the page is reloaded?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm fetching data from a local server, I want to put the response into `images` so I can render those urls afterwards

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(()=>{
  let id = '62432174021cfe441eb49bf7'

  findImages(id)
  .then(res=>{
     console.log(res.content)
     setImages(res.content)          
     console.log(images)          
  })
 },[])

)//useEffect
```

you see that `console.log(res.content)` ? it shows in console the following:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6243499ae6b17dc7de44fb0c",
    "chapterid": "62432174021cfe441eb49bf7",
    "url": "https://firebasestorage...",
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "624349b0e6b17dc7de44fb0e",
    "chapterid": "62432174021cfe441eb49bf7",
    "url": "https://firebasestorage...",
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "624349b7e6b17dc7de44fb10",
    "chapterid": "62432174021cfe441eb49bf7",
    "url": "https://firebasestorage...",
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "624349bde6b17dc7de44fb12",
    "chapterid": "62432174021cfe441eb49bf7",
    "url": "https://firebasestorage...",
  },
]
```

And you see that `console.log(images)` ? it's placed 2 lines after and it shows in console the following: `Array []`, So I'm getting a proper response from the server but when I try to put it into the useState variable it doesn't work, the funny thing is that when I `Ctrl + S` the project then `console.log(images)` gets the same display in the console as `console.log(res.content)`, which is what I want to happen without having to save the project.

I need that `image` to set the `res.content` from the start, I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvM9Ob4CHa0 the boy is doing the same as me but it works for him, look in the min `1:45, line: 30`, I don't know what's going on.

this is an interesting thread that I found [Why is useState() not setting the default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181908/why-is-usestate-not-setting-the-default-value) but I dont't think it's the same as my scenario, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setState` function of `useState` is async. Logging the state right after setting it, won't show the value you have just set.

However, it is guaranteed by the framework that the new value will be available in the next render cycle.

You can test this by logging the state `images` outside of the `useFocusEffect`.

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(()=>{
  let id = '62432174021cfe441eb49bf7'

  findImages(id)
  .then(res=>{
     console.log(res.content)
     setImages(res.content)                 
  })
 },[])

console.log(images)
```

You will notie two log messages. One with an empty array. After the state changes via `setImages`, you will see a second console.log due to a rerender. This time with the previously set value.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, this is a very simplified portion of the actual code, so its easy to understand the main issue. Based on your answer I could manage to solve it. Btw how do you do put color in the code here? mine is all black

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that this works for you! You can color the code here using the syntax highlighter of your choice. In this case this is JavaScript, thus you can write \```javascript CODE \```